# How to save data in a custom post type in wordpress before sending the email?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, contact-form-7

I have a problem in Wordpress. I want to make a hook on Contact Form 7, so that when the user clicks send, it first saves this information inside a custom post type.

Reading the documentation, I found this

// run the action 
do_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', $contact_form );

```
// define the wpcf7_before_send_mail callback 
function action_wpcf7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) { 

    //code

}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'action_wpcf7_before_send_mail', 10, 1 );
```

But I do not know how to continue. Has anyone done this and can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
function action_wpcf7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) { 

    $post_content = ''; // empty contebt
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
        $post_content .= $key.': '.$value.'
        '; //add each form field to content
    }

    $title = $_REQUEST['some field'].' '.$_REQUEST['some field2']; // generate dynamic title

    $t = time();
    $thash = md5($t);

    $my_query = array(
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $title ),
        'post_content'  => $post_content,
        'post_type' => 'your-post-type',
        'post_name' => $thash,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1
    );
    $data = wp_insert_post( $my_query );


    return $contact_form;
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'action_wpcf7_before_send_mail', 10, 1 );
```